# How can I load a WebForms page into an iframe without two full page renders from the server?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, iframe

I have a sort of shell page that contains filter controls and an iframe for displaying a gridview. When you click the 'filter' button, or when a timer is fired, filter data is collected from the filter controls and fed in the querystring to the gridview iframe, as shown:

```
var URL = "/mypage/gridview.aspx";
var dest = URL + '?' + getFilterData();
var frame = $('#gridiframe');
$.ajax({
    type: "HEAD",
    async: true,
    url: dest
}).success(function () {
    frame.attr('src', dest);
})
.error(loadError);
```

My conundrum is this: the gridview can be very costly to render. It performs a HUGE database trip and this method is causing the page to be rendered twice. The first time, the client just looks at the header to make sure the user is authenticated (page returns HTTP unauthorized if session has timed out) and that all the parameters are in a good format. But I don't want to change the iframe source to show an error message, I just want to call loadError which basically just notifies the user what went wrong.

Is there anything I can do with the client code to populate my iframe in only one exchange with the server?

edit: thanks all for your input. At the end of the day, I hate webforms. End of story.

Comment: Yes, but I would never recommend doing it..  First, it's fairly difficult, you'll have to do some funky encoding/json/hidden elements to load the view in the other view, then parse it out then insert the value into the iframe, very ugly.  But really doing that will create dependencies and increase maintenance, for what I would consider, almost no benefit.

Comment: @ErikPhilips the query that is run by the gridview page can take several seconds to run and this page is accessed all day long at 1-minute intervals by hundreds if not thousands of customers. Even if it's ugly, cutting our database load in half is a significant benefit.

Comment: So your REAL problem is the query/database... [And Ajax is actually a solution, not a problem (XY Problem)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/171858).  Instead, I would suggest speeding up the database/query/index or start caching values.  Loading via Ajax won't be significantly faster, and will actually hurt the initial load time of the iframe's parent.

Comment: The db hit is a pain point but it is already about as optimized as it's going to be. The query is dynamically generated and has to hit 10 or so fairly large tables. The query and results are different for every user based on permission level, account memberships, identity, and search criteria. The volume and variety of results can't be cached. Weeks of optimization on the backend wouldn't yield 25% improvement, whereas if this client issue could be fixed it would improve page response time by 50% and reduce database load by 50%. Believe me, I'm asking about a real problem, not a "solution".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of querying the iframe's source URL in the ajax query, query a different endpoint that doesn't run the same DB query. You said it does two things, 1 validate the user's login token is still valid and 2 that the filter parameters are valid.  Neither of those validation steps require running the query on the database that get the full query results. So, create a new API endpoint that does your basic validation, and if that returns a success message, then set the iframe source to what you want.

Another option is to return a HTML fragment, rather than a full HTML page, from gridview.aspx. Then your AJAX can replace the contents of a div with the HTML result if successful, rather than setting the iframe src, while still allowing you to handle errors.

A more trendy option (not saying it's better or worse, but certainly more aligned with the current web development industry) is to change gridview.aspx to a web service/api that returns the data in simplified json, then use a javascript framework, or template engine to generate the html table on the client itself.

Comment: Well, some good thoughts. With regard to your first, the page currently performs validation basically by running the full DB query and rendering the gridview. But I could do some more lightweight validation and verification in a webmethod. With regard to the second, I don't think that would work, because I rely on page lifecycle events and event handlers in gridview.aspx.cs. With regards to your last suggestion, I get it, but we don't have the development resources to rewrite the page, period.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe I'm over-simplifying things, but couldn't you just use a QueryString parameter in the second request?

```
$.ajax({
    type: "HEAD",
    async: true,
    url: dest
}).success(function () {
    frame.attr('src', dest + '&getGrid=true');
})
```

And then on the aspx page check if the QueryString is present.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //validate user always

    if (Request.QueryString["getGrid"] != null)
    {
        //rebuild grid 
    }
}
```

Comment: That _is_ an oversimplification, because the querystring variables have to be validated as well. The user is not likely to need validation, as we have a keep-alive iframe elsewhere on the page. Generally what is expected to be possibly erroneous are the filter parameters. Thanks for your input though.

Comment: I don't mean send all the filter parameters. `getGrid` is only there to make sure the the grid and thus the heavy sql query is not run the first time the url is called.

Comment: hmmmm. Yeah, I did misread your answer at first. This doesn't seem as much like a desirable pattern as Ziv's answer, but it might be easier to implement.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of an iFrame you can a normal `<div>` and load only the gridView from another page as follows:

First, Wrap the gridView around a container in the other page
Something like

`<div id='grid-wrapper'><!-- GridView here --></div>`

Then use your AJAX code like this to retrieve only the grid:

```
var URL = "/mypage/gridview.aspx";
var dest = URL + '?' + getFilterData();
var div = $('#divId');
$.ajax({
    type: "HEAD",
    async: true,
    url: dest
}).success(function (res) {
    div.html($('#grid-wrapper',$(res)).html); //this gets only the contents of grid-wrapper and not the whole page.
})
```

Comment: I had tried something like this, but it doesn't work for a couple reasons. One, you can't re-use the div. Two, I need the webforms page/control lifecycle events and they won't fire from this.

Comment: Yeah thats true. This method applies only when you have to load static content OR contents that can be handled by simple JS.